# WordPress – output categories, posts and images to JSON

Tags: php, json, wordpress

I'm trying to recreate a JSON file with a specific structure and only getting so far as I'm not that familiar with PHP.

I'd like to list all used/non-empty categories, then all posts within each category and then all images/other details used in each post.

I'm not sure how the code should look in the loop. I'd need the JSON to be *exactly* like below (brackets) as I'm feeding it to a D3 script:

```
{
    "project": "Farm", // website name
    "about": "What we have on the farm.",
    "categories": [ //post categories
        {
            "slug": "fruits",
            "title": "Fruits",
            "description": "All about fruits.",
            "posts": [ // all posts within a category
                {
                    "slug": "apples",
                    "title": "Apples",
                    "excerpt": "Apple trees and fruits.",
                    "tags": "tree, apple",
                    "post_images": [
                        { 
                            "id": 25, 
                            "title": "Apple trees.", 
                            "filename": "apple-trees.jpg", 
                            "desc": "Rows of apple trees.", 
                            "tags": "" 
                        },
                        (...)
```

The PHP script so far (in `functions.php`):

```
function export_to_json() {
    
    global $post;
    
    $post_args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
    );
    
    $cat_args = array(
        'orderby' => 'name',
        'order' => 'ASC'
    );
    
    $posts = array();
    
    $cats = get_categories( $cat_args );
    foreach( $cats as $cat ) {
        $query = new WP_Query( $post_args );
    
        while ( $query->have_posts() ): $query->the_post();
        
            $posts[] = array(
                'categories' => [
                    'title' => $cat->cat_name,
                    'description' => $cat->description,
                    'posts' => [
                        'title' => get_the_title(),
                        'excerpt' => get_the_excerpt(),
                        'images' => get_attached_media( 'image' ),
                        'tags' => get_tags()
                    ]
                ]
            );
            
        endwhile;
    
        wp_reset_query();   
        
    }

    $data = json_encode($posts, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    
    $upload_dir = wp_get_upload_dir();
    $file_name = date('Y-m-d') . '.json';
    $save_path = $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/' . $file_name;

    $f = fopen($save_path, "w");
    fwrite($f, $data);
    fclose($f);
}

add_action('save_post', 'export_to_json');
```

The script is wrong because categories get repeated for each post and I'd like all posts within a category to be properly nested.

Any help with this would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to print this data out in a theme file? Or just trying to export the data for another purpose?

Comment: You might need to add `global $post;` in your function in order to use the template functions such as get_the_title()

Comment: Just exporting to a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
function export_to_json() {
    
    global $post;
    
    $categories = array();
    
    $cat_args = array(
        'orderby' => 'name',
        'order' => 'ASC'
    );

    $cats = get_categories( $cat_args );
    
    foreach( $cats as $cat ) {
    
         $post_args = array(
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'category__in' => $cat->term_id
        );
    
        $get_posts = array();
        
        $posts = get_posts( $post_args  );
        
        foreach($posts as $post){
            
            $tags = get_the_tags($post->ID);
            $i = 0;
            $tag_names = '';
            $post_images = array();
            
            if( $tags) {
                foreach( $tags as $tag ) { $i++;
                    $comma = $i == count($tags) ? '' : ', ';
                    $tag_names .= $tag->name .  $comma;
                }
            }
            
           
            $images = get_post_gallery($post->ID, false);
            
            if($images){
                $image_ids = explode(",", $images['ids']);
                foreach ($image_ids as $image ){
                    $img = wp_prepare_attachment_for_js($image);
                    $post_images[] = array(
                        "id" => $img['id'], 
                        "title" => $img['name'], 
                        "filename" => $img['filename'],
                        "desc" => $img['description'], //Pulls the image description
                        'tags' => $tag_names
                    );
                }
                
            }
            
            
            $get_posts[] = array(
                'slug' => $post->post_name,
                'title' => get_the_title(),
                'excerpt' => get_the_excerpt(),
                'tags' => $tag_names,
                'post_images' =>  $post_images
            );
        }
        
        
            
        $categories[] = array(
            'slug' => $cat->slug,
            'title' => $cat->cat_name,
            'description' => $cat->description,
            'posts' => $get_posts
        );
        
    }
    
    $output = array(
        'project' => get_bloginfo('name'),
        'about' => get_bloginfo('description'),
        'categories' => $categories
    );

    $data = json_encode($output, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    
}
```

Comment: Thanks, almost there! Category key gets repeated in curly brackets `"categories": {...}, "categories": {...}` instead being an array like posts `"posts": [{...}, {...}]`. Also, how would I prepend the whole JSON with website title like this (please note the brackets): `{"project": site-title, "about": site-tagline, "categories": [{`?

Comment: So you want the array with categories listed?

Comment: Basically like [this](http://lenart.pl/libs/projects_new.json) – I need to recreate exactly that structure — array of categories with array of posts nested in each, then array of images. I forgot to specify the images would be from a post gallery, not all attachments as the featured image would be used separately. Thanks.

Comment: I've changed `$output = $categories = array();` to `$categories = array();` and `$output[] = array(...)` to `$output = array(...)` so the outermost square brackets are not included. Otherwise, it's what I was after, so I'm accepting the answer. Many thanks.